# "Object doesn't support this property or method" in IE8 and IE7

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I keep getting this error:

> Object doesn't support this property
>   or method

whenever I run my code in IE7 and IE8.  This is what code its stopping on:

```
_renderUploadTemplate: function(files){
    var that = this;
    return $.tmpl(
        this.options.uploadTemplate,
        $.map(files, function(file){
            return that._uploadTemplateHelper(file);
        }
    )
}
```

I am using jQuery-File-Upload by BlueImp.  Here is the link to the source files: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload.

this happens whenever I try to upload something, seems to work ok in other browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put this code in your document ready. Sometimes older versions of IE don't initialize things correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
_renderUploadTemplate: function(files){
    var that = this;
    return $.tmpl(
        this.options.uploadTemplate,
        $.map(files, function(file){
            return that._uploadTemplateHelper(file);
        }); //right here
    )
}
```

I think you're missing a parentheses.